# how to pass the sysdate value fom Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have a situation here where i need to pass the date as sysdate of db from the .net code using the Nhibernate here goes my code

```
 OfflineStatusChangeMonitor newstatusobj = new OfflineStatusChangeMonitor
                    {
                        NIK = demoFromDedup.NIK,
                        NIKStatus = new Status { Code = demoFromDedup.CurrentStatus.Code },
                        RegionId = Convert.ToInt16(demoFromDedup.RegionId),
                        LocalId = demoFromDedup.LocalId,
                        Updatedtime = DateTime.Now,
                        ServiceName = "XXXXX"

                    };
                    idmsRepository.Add<OfflineStatusChangeMonitor>(newstatusobj);
```

where add functions code is as follows

```
 public void Add<ENTITY>(ENTITY entity) where ENTITY : EntityBase
    {
        this.UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.Save(entity);
    }
```

now in this situation how can i set the values of updatedtime to SYSDATE of Oracle

i can not do it in the data base as i have the db s in many locations and am updating the data from wcf service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DateTime getdbdate()
        {
            var dt = this.UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("select sysdate from dual where rownum<2").UniqueResult();

            if (dt != null)

                return (DateTime)dt;
            else           

            return DateTime.Now;

        }
```

and then call this function to get the db date and then use this as the date time in your function

Comment: Is this there also a database-agnostic way to do this in Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Try using trigger. Then oracle database will update the field with SYSDATE when you update the record.

Comment: i have used the an function to fetch the sysdate and am using when needed any how thanx for ur guidence

Comment: @raghavendrav post your answer to this question with sample code and accept it as answer. It will help someone like you in future. And also this question will not come as unanswered feed.

Comment: public DateTime getdbdate()
        {
            var dt = this.UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("select sysdate from dual where rownum<2").UniqueResult();

            if (dt != null)

                return (DateTime)dt;
            else           

            return DateTime.Now;

        }
write a function like this and get the call this funciton when needed the db date and the use it